# bash: "time time cmd" is not working after update

Tags: bash, time

I just updated my bash and now I can't use the `time time` command that worked fine before update.

The idea of `time time cmd` is: first `time` is bash builtin function, and second `time` is `/usr/bin/time` program. `cmd` is the program to be timed.

Usage of `time time` was short and easy to remember way to see both fine printed user/sys/real times and page fault stats:

```
$ time time false
Command exited with non-zero status 1
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.01elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+163minor)pagefaults 0swaps

real    0m0.035s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

First line is exit status of the cmd (if non-zero), second is compact time stats from `/usr/bin/time`, third is additional info from `/usr/bin/time` with pagefault stats. Then there are three lines from bash's `time` with more detailed timing info (3 digits after point).

Question is: why newer bash ignores second `time` as /usr/bin/time? What was changed and why?

How can I patch bash to return old style of parsing time?

I thinks there were changes in bash's `parse.y` which is bison file. Here the diff http://code.metager.de/source/diff/gnu/bash/parse.y?r2=%2Fgnu%2Fbash%2Fparse.y%40509a4430ae72aec10896713435e84f5b27675763&r1=%2Fgnu%2Fbash%2Fparse.y%4089a92869e56aba4e4cab2d639c00a86f0545c862

Comment: What if you use the full path of it?

Comment: Its okay (`/usr/bin/time`), but I want to use `time time`. I think, error is here in parse.y in bash 4.2 ... : http://code.metager.de/source/diff/gnu/bash/parse.y?r2=%2Fgnu%2Fbash%2Fparse.y%40509a4430ae72aec10896713435e84f5b27675763&r1=%2Fgnu%2Fbash%2Fparse.y%4089a92869e56aba4e4cab2d639c00a86f0545c862 near TIMEOPT/TIMEIGN maybe

Comment: How about making an alias? `alias time='time /usr/bin/time'` -- and then you only have to write it once.

Comment: Why don't you just create a format for `/usr/bin/time` which produces exactly the information you want in exactly the format you want it, and then alias something like `t` to an invocation of that? I don't see what the built-in time is giving you that a `/usr/bin/time` format string wouldn't.

Comment: What versions of `bash` did you upgrade from and to? (Although I tend to agree with rici: just set the `TIME` environment variable to include the information you want, and you can use `\time cmd` to quickly access the external `time` program that is shadowed by the `bash` keyword `time`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this behaviour was changed in bash, but after some thought I have suggestion to how to get it back to the way it was.

As I suggested in the comments, the easiest is to create an alias:

```
alias time='time /usr/bin/time'
```

but this changes the behaviour to use the "double time" every time. I started thinking that you might *want* to specify it two times. Of course, you could just rename the alias to `timetime` and be done with it. But if that's still not good enough, you can get the old behaviour back by adding a function and an alias to your startup script:

```
mytime() {
    if [ "$1" = "time" ]; then
        shift
        time /usr/bin/time $@
    else
        time $@
    fi
}
alias time=mytime
```

At least on my computer, this works fine.